# Integrating a min function in MATLAB

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I learn how to evaluate a integral using the int() function in MATLAB, but if there is an integral whose integrant involves a min function, like $\int^{-1}_{1} \int^{1}_{0} \min(x,y) \text{dxdy}$, can we use MATLAB to find an analytical formula?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I change the tag.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?